# Unable to import UTabs, UCard modules from nuxt/ui in one of my locals

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I have three locals and I’m unable to import the UTabs and UCard modules from nuxt/ui in one of them. I confirmed yesterday that it works without any issues in the other locals.

Here are the versions I’m using:

```
"nuxt": "3.9.0",
"@nuxt/ui": "npm:@nuxt/ui-edge@latest",
```

And here’s my package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@nuxt/ui": "npm:@nuxt/ui-edge@latest",
}
```

And my nuxt.config.ts modules:

```
modules: ["@nuxt/ui", "@pinia/nuxt", "nuxt-lodash", "@nuxt/image"],
```

I’ve confirmed that the modules are installed. However, I’m getting an “Unknown HTML tag UCard” error for the UTabs and UCard modules from nuxt/ui. I’ve tried deleting the node_modules and reinstalling them, and I’ve also tried running npm ci, but it still says it can’t find them.

What else should I try?